# More than 1 requirejs task in grunt for different optimization options

Tags: requirejs, gruntjs, r.js, grunt-contrib-requirejs

I use r.js to cobble together all the `js` code in my SPA into 1 file. I use grunt's `grunt-contrib-requirejs' task for this, with the following:

```
requirejs: {
  compile: {
    options: {
      name: 'app',
      out: 'build/js/app.js',
      baseUrl: 'app',
      mainConfigFile: 'config/main.js',
      preserveLicenseComments: true,
      optimize: "none"
    }
  }
}
```

I also use a build task that zips the build folder into a zip file for me to send to our company's change management folks.

I would like to have two requirejs tasks - one that uglifies (for sending to CM) and one that doesn't (during development). Is this possible? I tried creating a new task with a different name and grunt yelled at me... should be simple. Is this possible? Are there any reasons not to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually it is very simple:

```
requirejs: {
    compile: {
        options: {
            ...
            optimize: "none"
        }
    },
    compileForProduction: {
        options: {
            ...
            optimize: "uglify2"
        }
    }
}
```

(options are same as yours, with any diffs between the two that are required, e.g. `optimize`)

Run it with:

```
grunt requirejs:compileForProduction
```

or in `Gruntfile.js`:

```
grunt.registerTask("prod", ["requirejs:compileForProduction"]);
```

and:

```
grunt prod
```

Comment: This was so easy, thank you - exactly what I needed. Thanks again for taking the time to help me out!